# I tried to use hover on <li>, but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hover

I tried to use hover on these `<li>`s, but somehow it doesn't work. Because it's the first time I've seen something like this, I'm so confused.

```css
.container1 ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  margin-top: 515px;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container1 ul li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2d2a2a;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #fab203;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.container1 ul li:hover {
  background-color: #fab203;
  color: #2d2a2a;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div id="album">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">2</li>
    <li id="3">3</li>
    <li id="4">4</li>
    <li id="5">5</li>
    <li id="6">6</li>
    <li id="7">7</li>
    <li id="8">8</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What effect are you want to get?

Comment: I'm trying to something basic like change background Color.But the hover doesn't work

Comment: Your code work fine. Background color change on hover element.

Comment: ok then there must be a problem somewhere else in my code..Hard to figure out

Comment: I think you defined the attributes of this element elsewhere in the style sheet.

Comment: I've solve the problem, there is another div was on top of these li elements and covered them.Thats why hover doesn't work.Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/517jfhvb/16/).
Due to `position: absolute;` positioning, unordered list has been disappeared from the view of `.container` div. And also there is a issue in `</ul>` tag. It is not properly closed.
Your rest of code works fine.

```css
.container1 ul{
/* position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-180px;
margin-top:515px;*/
display:block;
list-style-type: none; 
}
.container1 ul li{
float:left;
background-color:#2d2a2a;
text-align: center;
border:2px solid #fab203;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
line-height: normal;
letter-spacing: normal;
color:black;
width:25px;
height:20px;
margin-left:20px; 
}
.container1 ul li:hover{
background-color:#fab203;
color:#2d2a2a;
cursor:hand;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div id="album"></div>
  <ul>    
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">2</li>
    <li id="3">3</li>
    <li id="4">4</li>
    <li id="5">5</li>
    <li id="6">6</li>
    <li id="7">7</li>
    <li id="8">8</li>             
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
    .container1 ul {
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-180px;
        margin-top:515px;
        display:block;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .container1 ul li {
        float:left;
        background-color:#2d2a2a;
        text-align: center;
        border:2px solid #fab203;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color:white;
        width:25px;
        height:20px;
        margin-left:20px; 
    }
    .container1 ul li:hover {
        background-color:#fab203;
        color:#2d2a2a;
        cursor:hand;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container1">
        <div id="album">
        </div>
        <ul>    
            <li id="1">1</li>
            <li id="2">2</li>
            <li id="3">3</li>
            <li id="4">4</li>
            <li id="5">5</li>
            <li id="6">6</li>
            <li id="7">7</li>
            <li id="8">8</li>
        <ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```